# Why does Kylo Ren wear a mask?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, kylo-ren

Is there an explanation on why Kylo Ren wears that mask in *The Force Awakens*? It even has a voice synthesizer and everything.

It makes him look like a Darth Vader fanboy and really tries to be/look/sound like him.

It doesn’t look like he needs it or anything.

Comment: Self-conscious.

Comment: "Makes him look like a Vader fanboy" Have you seen the movie? That's exactly what he is.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: Indeed... pimples and all... Most people would not find a teen frightening... maybe that's why he needs a mask.

Comment: @thkala Adam Driver is 32 and Harrison Ford is 73. Absolutely not a teenager...

Comment: Maybe all Knights of Ren wear such masks? There was another Knight of Ren, played by an actor I'd have recognised if he had been not masked, but [I'm not sure when exactly he featured or what his character looked like](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111350/when-did-the-other-knight-of-ren-feature-played-by-mark-stanley-is-anything)

Comment: He doesn't look scary without a mask. He looks like you can cuddle him and that he's someone you can walk around the park and get ice cream with.

Comment: @fabrice-d, you have to admit that even if his age remains unknown and that we can assume that Ren is more than 20, such haircut makes him look like a member of One Direction.  Without his mask, , facing Solo, he looks just like a teen having a big argument with his father

Comment: Well, man, that's your opinion. Johnny Depp's over 50 with long hair. Iggy Pop too and he's over 70. Also a lot of metal singers. Long hair can be badass and adult.

Comment: There's chronological age and then there's maturity level. I rate Kylo Ren's emotional maturity in the 5-13 range. I classify the "Prime Order", led by two such emotional adolescents, as an "emo boy band in space". I have a hard time not confusing the name with "One Direction".

Comment: Related question: [Why does Kylo Ren wear a mask?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/49826/49)

Comment: He is a young Severus Snape trying to be Darth Vader.

Comment: Ren hates Muggles so he wants to scare them into thinking Voldemort has returned.  Remember the Star Wars universe contains our planet which, and since magicked special people appear in both universes we can assume that the jedi temple was the first hogwarts.

Comment: It's a fashion statement. Vader wore a mask for medical reasons, but it caught on.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Psychological warfare. Vader was the death dealing wizard right hand man of the evil emperor for well over a generation. More than likely, his image is still enough to put a good portion of the population in fear. By taking up the mantle, so to speak, he is making a clear statement about the terror and power that he represents.

To put this in perspective, imagine if, in the 1970's (let alone today) someone rose to power wearing a certain uniform with a red sash around his arm with a funny symbol on it, a swept haircut, and a little mustache. His belief and intent would be instantly clear to everybody around him. He would be drawing upon the associations with the look of that person, using it as a tool. In the 1970's you would have a combination of people who survived the war as well as children born and raised in its shadow, all completely familiar with the faces of those famous people associated with it.

Just so with the time period in Force Awakens, we are a little more than a generation past from the downfall of the Emperor, and the tremors from the war continue to resonate.

Comment: It's not often someone Godwins a SE question - ontopic. +1

Comment: I....thanks? I thought it was a perfectly legit simile. The thing is, you'll notice I didn't name anyone and yet by describing a few superficial aspects of the person, you knew EXACTLY who I was referring to. That's my point. That's the power that Kylo Ren was drawing upon.

Comment: If you want a real-life illustration for your second paragraph, check out the imagery of the Greek political party Golden Dawn

Comment: Right. It's not necessarily JUST psychological warfare. I'm certain he was obsessed with Vader, and I think the two combined so that he would harvest the power of that imagery that he was so obsessed with to try to imbue it to himself.

Comment: In other words, he wears it because he thinks it makes him look badass. Just like every other 20-something male!

Comment: Sure, the Hydra mentality- one Stormtrooper is all Stormtroopers.

Comment: After getting grazed by Rey, he now has a reason to hide behind the helmet, furthering his descent into darkness and conforming him even closer to the image of his idol, Vader. A point I'm sure will be explored in later movies.

Comment: It's also worth noting that anything with a dehumanizing effect, like masks and distorted voices, can trigger discomfort and fear in an observer (it's an effect that is very commonly used in the horror genre.) This would further increase its psychological effect on his enemies.

Comment: @Crashworks try 14-15

Answer (score 52):

Kylo Ren is obsessed with Darth Vader,

> his maternal grandfather.

He tries to imitate Vader’s appearance even though there is no medical need for him to cover his face.

Additionally, the mask and helmet are worn for the intimidating appearance: They hide Kylo Ren’s facial expressions, let him appear larger and make him inapproachable to his underlings and enemies.

Helmet and mask as pieces of armor also offer protection against flying debris and would be sensible pieces of equipment for explosion heavy assault missions such as the ones seen in *The Force Awakens*.

Comment: I would more guess its the intimidation effect. Armor in star wars is just......lets face it even storm trooper armor does not withstand a single blast....or kick

Comment: @Thomas ...and apparently only filters smoke.

Comment: The general characterization of Kylo Ren in the movie definitely supports this answer, I think.

Comment: @deinlebenandern never spoke out against that. only thing I'm not so sure about is the "protection" part :)

Comment: Worth mentioning is that Han Solo says as much. "Take off that mask, you don't need it".

Comment: To quote Bane, not Darth Bane, just Bane: "Nobody cared who I was before I put on this mask".

Comment: Now I can only think of him as Dark Helmet from Spaceballs.

Answer (score 36):

Canonical answer: during Rei's dream sequence when she picks up the light sabre, we see a group of characters all wearing similar masks. (From the screenshot below it looks as if the masks are not all identical, but they are similar in appearance.)

[image: Kylo Ren, in black, fully masked and covered, carrying his cross-hilted red lightsaber switched on at his side, walks through a rainy dark scene with 6 other figures dressed entirely in black, helmeted and carrying a variety of weapons]

From the context of the movie we can surmise that these are the Knights of Ren. Thus, the reason Kylo Ren wears such a mask is that he is (or was) a Knight of Ren, and the mask is part of his uniform. Of course, it might indeed be that this uniform is inspired by Darth Vader, as the other answers suggest.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer is ignored - it really seems to be the correct one, while the most up-voted (and chosen) answer is just speculation.

Answer (score 21):

There isn't any canonical explanation yet, or at least it isn't made obvious by the movie.

It is heavily hinted that Darth Vader is Kylo Ren's role model, so it's no wonder that Kylo Ren wants to look like Vader.

> He meditates next to Vader's mask.

> When he tries to read Rey's mind and the telepathic connection he has established backfires, causing Rey to read his feelings, we learn that he fears he will never be as strong as Vader.

But it is also heavily hinted that Kylo Ren looks more intimidating, fearsome and powerful than he actually is.

> He is not a skilled Force user. First, his roster of tricks is pretty limited. He can do Force telekinesis, Force telepathy and... that's about it. No Force throw, no Force jump, no saber throw, no Force lightning. Second, he fails both times he tries to use his powers on other Force-sensitive people. When he tried to read the map out of Rey's mind, it backfired on him and caused Rey to read his mind. When he tried to pull Luke's lightsaber out of the snow, it actually went to Rey.

> At the end of the movie, Snoke says that Kylo Ren must "complete his training".

> Kylo Ren's lightsaber has a very rough blade (see the [official movie poster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtRyp.jpg) for comparison of Kylo Ren's lightsaber and Anakin Skywalker's one), hinting to a less-than-stellar build quality. By the way, it is canonically established by Star Wars Clone Wars season 5, episode 7 ("A Test of Strength") that building a lightsaber is a test of Force-wielding.

> The Dark Side of the force provides "abilities some consider to be unnatural" (Palpatine in *Revenge of the Sith*) and excessive usage of these powers permanently changes the user's appearance. Now, when Kylo Ren takes off his mask for the first time, he looks... handsome? innocent? disappointing for a Darksider? Either way, he obviously isn't yet intimate with the Dark Side.

Finally, let us not forget that Kylo Ren is one of the Knights of Ren.

> The movie doesn't really explore that part of the story. We know that Kylo Ren is one of the Knights of Ren, but we are never told about any other characters in the same group. It seems that current consensus among fans is that the Knights of Ren can be seen in the Force vision that Rey had when she touched Anakin's lightsaber. [This is the best image I could find](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaFVu.jpg). As we can see, most of these people wear masks. <s>I am not sure about the guy with the spear, the second from right. I think we can see his eyes, nose and some facial structure that goes around his mouth (maybe coincidentally, but not unlike [Sith race](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrYHR.png)). But this might be a mask after all</s>. [Wookieepedia has another screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCPkI.jpg) that leaves little doubt that the guy with the spear wears a mask, too.

So, maybe wearing a mask is just something that Knights of Ren do.

Comment: On the point of force powers. He is quite strong in those he shows (see beginning the blaster scene). But else he really looks either rough or way less trained than the guys in the prequels. Guess it will be shown in episode 8 what is up with him there (or if it was artistic freedom).

Comment: Concerning your first point, it is more than heavily hinted: the scene where we learn that Dark Vador is Kylo Ren's grandfather is when KR is speaking to DV's mask, asking for help and guidance.

Comment: Ooh. your last paragraph might be the answer to [a question I literally just asked](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111350/when-did-the-other-knight-of-ren-feature-played-by-mark-stanley-is-anything)

Comment: @MirosławZalewski: Found it (well actually, I found something clearer), [this answer discusses how Disney changed canon](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/910/how-is-canonicity-of-derivative-works-determined-for-star-wars). But _The Clone Wars_ is **in** that new canon, which the earlier thing I'd seen didn't mention. So your answer is entirely within canon.

Answer (score 11):

Canon answer, courtesy of *TFA Visual Dictionary page 24 ("Kylo Ren")*:

> Patterned after the battle gear of the Knights of Ren, **Kylo Ren's helmet conceals his identity and adds to his imposing demeanor**. Servomotors drive articulated arms that separate the face mask from the helmet, letting Kylo remove the black form to state down his opponents with incontained malice.

Also, on page 26 ("Dark Warrior"), the mask is called "Battered Combat Helmet".

So, there seem to be 4 "Why"s:

1. To conceal his identity.

   This is important. TFA VD also lets us know that:

   > **his birth name is never spoken by decree of the Supreme Leader**.
2. To intimidate.

   Because let's face it, Adam Driver just Does Not Look Intimidating. More in-universe, the existing answer by @Broklynite unpacks this angle very well.
3. For combat protection. It is "battered" after all
4. As a uniform

   In the script/film, Snoke calls him "Even you, **master of the Knights of
   Ren**, have never faced such a test."

   As such, wearing the gear common to the group you're a master of makes sense.

Answer (score 8):

Lots of Sith wear masks. Take this quote about Darth Revan.

> Without the mask he looked more human. It was easier to remember he was just a man, with all the weaknesses and vulnerabilities that implied. With the mask, however, Revan was an icon, a symbol. He was the shaper of history, an individual defined by his actions rather than his thoughts, feelings, and beliefs.

- [*The Old Republic: Revan*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Old_Republic:_Revan)

Comment: Kylo Ren isn't a Sith.

Comment: @RogueJedi What is he then? A Dark Jedi? Something different?

Comment: @approachingdarknessfish http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110922/is-kylo-ren-a-sith

Comment: @JakeGould Maul was a [male Dathomirian](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Nightbrothers).

Answer (score 6):

He's a mentally unstable young man looking for a direction in life. Disappointed with his father whom he sees as a foolish old man, he strives for greatnes. As it often happens, the dark side looks more glamorous. Seductive, if you will. He is trying to be a new Vader.

Comment: Good thing he found "One Direction" then... oh I mean the "Prime Order" or whatever it's called. They need to find a drummer though.

Answer (score 5):

During the exchange on the bridge, Han says, "Take off your mask, you don't need it." Which is followed by a discussion of how Ren "destroyed" Ben Solo. The mask is an integral part of that transformation and the erasure of his old identity, along with the intimidation discussed above.

And he selected that mask and voice manipulator to be as much like Vader as possible.

Comment: It's also lost on the Starkiller Base, so we'll see in the next episode if he gets a new mask and if he copies the design (maybe a Knights of Ren standard?) or does something new. He's also got a brand new face scar to hide....

Answer (score 1):

I think one reason he wears the mask is to show that he is no longer Ben Solo.

Comment: You may want to add some more detail.  Overly terse answers are often downvoted.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure being a Vader fanboy is a big part of it, but the mask probably has a HUD and all the stuff the stormtrooper helmets have. Example, when he sees Finn stop shooting and have panic attack, he knew exactly what number he was. Same as the troopers know who each other are just by looking at the time.

Answer (score -2):

On top of the reasons above, Kylo Ren sees who he is and who he used to be as two distinct people, just as Vader did. I believe the mask helps with this, which is why in the climactic scene he was asked to remove it.

Comment: "Your son is gone. He was weak and foolish, like his father". I'm not saying he's Two-Face, I'm saying that he has deliberately adopted a different persona and the mask is part of that.

Comment: While I think your answer is valid, you might want to add some more content or references to it to make it more appealing to the user base.

Comment: While this may be true about Vader, it's not clear that he saw the mask as having anything to do with his transformation. He didn't adopt a mask (or a red lightsaber, for that matter) as part of his initial Vader persona. He attacked the Jedi temple as well as the Separatist headquarters with an uncovered face and his unmodified blue Jedi lightsaber. He later picked up the mask for medical reasons, and built a red lightsaber to replace the blue one which Obi Wan had taken from him. I'm sure he felt a mask helped his persona, but that wasn't the reason he picked it up.