# When did another "Knight of Ren" played by Mark Stanley appear in “The Force Awakens?” Is anything known about his role in the film?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, actors, actor-identification, knights-of-ren

One of the interesting mysteries in *The Force Awakens* is the origin and nature of the “Knights of Ren”. We learn quite a lot about Kylo Ren (Adam Driver), but little to nothing about what I presume are his peers in the “Knights of Ren” -  although I personally think it’s hinted that:

> …they might be the Dark-side corrupted survivors of Luke’s unsuccessful attempt to train a new Jedi order.

Looking at [the cast list for *The Force Awakens* on IMDB](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt2488496/fullcredits/cast?ref_=m_ttfc_3), I saw that the actor [Mark Stanley](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm4440305/) (who was in *Game Of Thrones* as Grenn, Jon Snow’s burly friend on the wall) was cast as an unnamed *Knight of Ren*.

But I don’t remember seeing him in the film (I’m sure I’d recognise him if not masked or rendered CGI), or in fact seeing *anyone* who looked like a [non-Kylo] “Knight of Ren.” A search via Google Images just returns pictures of Kylo.

When and where did Mark Stanley appear? What did he do? And what (if anything) do we know about his character? If there’s anything in the novelisation, that’s welcome information as well.

There’s only *one possible* scene I can think of:

> The villainous character in Rey’s flashback? But that character looked exactly like Kylo, with an identical lightsaber. I interpreted that as a premonition of the forest scene.

Comment: Not a sourced answer, but it's entirely possible he's credited for a scene that will show up as a DVD extra. :-\

Comment: I had the same questions about Jorge Leon Martinez's uncredited appearance as *Jedi* from the IMDB page. I suppose that could've been another blink-and-miss-it/flashback scene.

Comment: @raisinghellyer Wasn't there a flashback scene if someone getting butchered? I think there was, I think it was the last second before she pulled away. Maybe that was your Jedi?

Comment: [Answer to your question from **IrisBest**](http://boards.theforce.net/threads/the-knights-of-ren.50032947/page-98#post-53059796).
I'd also recommend you to read his adjacent comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Knight of Ren played by Mark Stanley is this guy who gets killed by Kylo Ren’s lightsaber through his back:
https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSequels/comments/isnvh1/did_anything_actually_come_of_this_vision_in_tfa/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=iossmf

@DavidW noted Mark Stanley himself confirmed this via Twitter:

> Hello @MarkStanley12 Just curious, in Star Wars TFA did u play the guy in that vision scene in the rain, who gets killed by Kylo Ren?

> Mark Stanley @MarkStanley12 certainly did! A privilege to even make it into thr greatness that is SW

https://mobile.twitter.com/MarkStanley12/status/681944746907013120

Comment: https://twitter.com/MarkStanley12/status/681944746907013120 See the last comment on the question.

Answer (score 23):

There was a flashback scene where SEVERAL Knights of Ren appeared (no good screenshot yet, sorry), surrounding Kylo Ren, not just him alone.

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 I'd misremembered this as being more like the snow-covered forest. I'd accept this but I can't think of any reason why just one figure in this septiren would be a credited actor

Comment: Perhaps the others aren't accredited and SAG-registered?

Comment: Actually Mark Hamill wasn't even advertised, people took care of building hype towards THAT specific thing. I haven't seen a single Star Wars teaser/promo/etc which had the intent to 'sell' Hamill/Luke