# Is there any knowledge on who the six other members of the "Knights of Ren" are?

Tags: star-wars, knights-of-ren

Looking at the wiki page on this group, it says that the Knights of Ren consist of Snoke (the leader), Kylo Ren (one of the knights), and six others. Are there any clues or canon details that indicate who the other six people are?

Comment: One of the other knights was a role in the film creditted to Mark Stanley ([see this related question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111350)), so it's speculated there might be a deleted scene with this knight in, but I think we don't know anything else about them. See also [Where were the Knights of Ren during the events of The Force Awakens?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114636) (where the answer is also, we don't really know... )

Comment: Only speculation, but after meeting Kylo, I'm willing to bet their names are Grumpy, Happy, Sleepy, Bashful, Sneezy, and Doc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where were the Knights of Ren during the events of The Force Awakens?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114636/where-were-the-knights-of-ren-during-the-events-of-the-force-awakens)

Comment: "Who are" is a fundamentally different question than "Where are". For example: "Who are all the known members of the new Resistance?" vs. "Where was the new Resistance based out of?"

Comment: this question http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113671/what-is-the-origin-background-of-the-knights-of-ren has some similarities, basically we don't know anything about them YET.

Comment: We are the Knights of the Ren table. We dance whenever we're able...

Answer (score 4):

We now have a great deal of information about the [Knights of Ren](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Knights_of_Ren) including their identities ([Ap'lek](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ap%27lek), [Cardo](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Cardo), [Kuruk](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Kuruk), [Trudgen](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Trudgen), [Ushar](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ushar) and [Vicrul](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Vicrul)), that their order was originally founded by a man named [Ren](https://renandstimpy.fandom.com/wiki/Ren_H%C3%B6ek), that they're all mildly Force sensitive and that they report to Kylo Ren (but ultimately to Snoke/Palpatine).

> An enclave of masked warriors wielding distinct weapons for ranged and
> close­quarter combat, the Knights of Ren are elite, fearsome enforcers
> of Kylo Ren's dark will.
>
> [image]
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars Databank: Knights of Ren](https://www.starwars.com/databank/knights-of-ren)</sup></sub>

<s>As of 1st <s>April</s> <s>May</s> <s>June</s> July 2016, we have no information about the identities of the [Knights of Ren](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Knights_of_Ren) nor any information about their backgrounds or histories.</s>

Comment: But I'm sure eventually each of them will have a movie of his or her own.

Comment: @broklynite - Under the old EU we could have expected each one to have their own book series. Now it's not nearly so certain.

Comment: Under the new Disney, however, it'll be movies.