# What happened to the rest of Luke's pupils?

Tags: star-wars

In *The Last Jedi* we find out that

> Luke started a training academy for future Jedi Knights. Ben Solo/Kylo Ren turned against Luke, burnt down the school and fled. He gathered a gang of followers around him from the ex-pupils and killed any who would not join him.
>  What happened to those pupils that sided with Kylo Ren? I think we see them gathered together in Rey's Force-vision in *The Force Awakens*.

Is there any further info on these characters in current canon?

Comment: They're still in his eye-sockets.

Comment: [Very related](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/117021/58193)

Comment: Didn't Ben take them all when he left?

Comment: @shreedhar Take them where? To do what?

Comment: @TheDarkLord Those guys dressed in red standing guard around Snoke all the time. Maybe they are the missing pupils. Their weapons did seem like modified sabers. (well, at least that's what I thought).

Comment: I agree it's a poorly written question, but I think that at its heart, it's trying to find the same info as you - what happened to the other pupils? The other asker likely mentioned the Knights of Ren since it's such a popular theory. And yeah, I'd probably just throw a bounty on that one looking for an authoritative answer.