# How does Anakin 'bringing balance to the force' impact on The Force Awakens?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, the-force, darth-vader, prophecy

In Star Wars Episode 1 [we hear Mace Windu](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Chosen_One) say:

> "You refer to the prophecy of the one who will bring balance to the Force. You believe it's this…boy?"

So I get that we had lots of good Jedi, and not many bad Sith, and so Anakin comes along in Episodes I-VI and the good guys and the bad guys are more or less even. So we have a 'balance' of sorts.

But the title "*The Force Awakens*" hints at the idea that not only is the force 'balanced', it is also asleep (since nearly all the good Jedi got killed off in Episode III).

So do we still care about the force being 'balanced'? Or will we discover a new meaning of 'balance'?

**Assumptions:**

- Not asking for theories about future episodes, just asking about "*The Force Awakens*" and how it interacts with the prophecy. Anything is possible in future episodes.

My question is: **How does Anakin 'bringing balance to the force' impact on The Force Awakens?**

Comment: The Force woke up and realized it had bad morning breath and urently needed to brush its teeth. Watch and see if DIsney won't make THAT into a children's book.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless I misread your question, you are not interpreting what the "balance" means correctly. That, or Lucas isn't (which, to be honest, I would happily decide is the correct option)

As per [George Lucas's DVD comments for ROTS](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Wookieepedia:April_Fools'_Day_2012/Chosen_One):

> in the films 4, 5, and 6, in which Anakin's offspring redeem him and allow him to fulfill the prophecy where he brings balance to the Force **by doing away with the Sith and getting rid of evil in the universe**..."

How that relates to Episode VII is unclear and largely depends on **[whether Supreme Leader Snoke is Darth Plagueis](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110876/is-there-evidence-to-suggest-that-supreme-leader-snoke-is-darth-plagueis)**.

However, as per numerous statements by J.J. Abrams, and barring that Plagueis twist/fantheory, **[the Sith are gone](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111759/are-the-sith-completely-gone)**, so Anakin did complete the Prophecy

Comment: Sadly, what the real defintion of "balance" should mean in Star Wars, you have to go off of what Lucas said it is unless Disney redefines it, so good answer.