# Do the Knights of Ren follow the Rule of Two?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, knights-of-ren

The Knights of Ren are a new (new to me) organisation who seem to be somewhat similar to Sith - [but they aren't actually Sith](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/110922/21267).

I'd like to know though, **Do the Knights of Ren follow the Rule of Two?**

So far I've only seen, or heard of two Knights of Ren:

- Kylo Ren and
- Supreme Leader Snoke (not confirmed, but you know)

Does this mean that there are only ever two? One master and one apprentice? Similar to the Sith practice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### No.

Given that we see what looks like about ***seven*** of them in *The Force Awakens*, the [Knights of Ren](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Knights_of_Ren) don't follow the Rule of Two.

[image]

The Force Awakens: Visual Dictionary indicates that *the group* Rey saw in her vision were the Knights of Ren.

> Rey, a Force-sensitive scavenger who hailed from Jakku, saw the Knights of Ren in a vision.

We already know Kylo and Snoke are members. The vision however was just of Kylo with others huddled around him. Since Snoke wasn't in that vision, calling that *group* the Kights (plural) of Ren indicates that there are *more* than just two of them. This seems to indicate that **the Knights of Ren don't follow the Rule of Two.**

Comment: We *KNOW* that Kylo Ren is a member/master of the Knights of Ren, but do we *KNOW* that Snoke is also a member? He hasn't adopted the Ren surname.  Most online references I can find on this suggest the Knights might just work for Snoke but not necessarily follow him, like Kylo does.

Comment: 2, 7. ["We don't do too good in math here"](http://endernews.com/iffiles.php?s=48)

Comment: @RemyLebeau I guess we don't know _for sure_ that Snoke is a Knight of Ren. [That doesn't change the fact that Kylo and 6 other people are called "Knights of Ren" in the Visual Dictionary, indicating they don't follow the Rule of Two.] :)

Answer (score -1):

What we know:
Knights of Ren are NOT Sith. They don't follow the rule of two created by Darth Bane.

We know, some canon, some not, that there are many Force users besides Siths and Jedis.

There's Dark Jedis, Witches of Dathomir, Sith pure race, etc.

We know that, or they are to naive, or they're not so greedy as the Sith so they don't need the role ot two. Maybe they even WERE HIDEN from the Sith!!!

My theory, sorry to not append some material here, but everything is so fresh and new, my theory is that **knights of Ren were CREATED BY VADER!!!**

We know from canon that Darth Vader wanted to kill Darth Sidius, and called Luke to enjoy it. (Episode VI).

Maybe Vader trained in secret Snoke willing to kill Sidius and set up his own empire.

This would add A LOT to Kylo Ren's motivation!!! Knowing that here's in a institution created by his grand father.

As we know from Episode VII, Kylo fears he will not be as great as Vader, and we know that he wants to resume what Vader started. A new order...