# What qualifies an order to be Sith?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, sith

Darth Bane's order of Sith Lords are the last true Sith. After Anakin Skywalker brought an end to the order, it can be said that there are no more Sith in the galaxy to carry on the line. When Palpatine was reborn, he did not successfully ensure the Sith's survival through any successor either. Yet we know there are multiple orders of dark side users since Palpatine's reign as Lord of the Sith - both Imperial and Reborn - and while some of these orders aren't considered Sith by their enemies (eg. the Jedi), some others are indeed considered as Sith, such as Jacen Solo, Lumiya, and Darth Krayt.

The line had been broken, so how has the blade been remade? What does it take for one to be called a Sith again?

Comment: If the Sith go extinct, who exactly is going to stop others from taking up the mantle and qualifying themselves as Sith?  The "true" Sith you refer to can also be considered untrue, since they were not members of the original Sith species.

Comment: But if you talk to others around here, we frequently distinguish between "just dark siders" and Sith, and that isn't necessarily restricted to Bane's Sith. We also consider some that come after as Sith but not others. This is defined in the EU. That's why I ask why some are considered such but not others. What does it take for Jedi, commoners, the members themselves and Star Wars fans to agree they are Sith?

Comment: You included Legends. The answers are very different between Legends canon and current canon, since Legends includes *many* broken lines.

Comment: @thegreatjedi `What does it take for Jedi, commoners, the members themselves and Star Wars fans to agree` Endless discussions and clashing of ideas until no one can be bothered to argue about it anymore. Whoever is left arguing their point will get the (now meaningless) victory of being considered right.

Answer (score 3):

The title of "Sith" isn't given by the public, it's more of a self-proclaimed title/group - at least after the fall of the original Sith Empire. One could argue that anybody claiming to be a Sith after Sidious is just kidding themselves and shouldn't be counted or from another point of view, anyone after the fall of the *original* Sith could be excluded - including everyone in the line of Bane. The only people with the right to exclude anyone would be "true" Sith - however we define that - and there's nobody left to speak up.

**To answer your question, it seems all it takes to be able to call themselves "Sith" is identifying with some or most of the Sith ideals/philosophies and then labeling themselves as a new incarnation of the order. It doesn't really have anything to do with meeting a certain criteria.**

Those philosophies include the Rule of Two (although this wasn't instituted until Darth Bane and was abandoned by Darth Krayt) and the Sith Code, authorized in 6900 BBY by Sorzus Syn and reinforced by Darth Bane, originally appearing in the Knights of the Old Republic video game:

> Peace is a lie, there is only passion.
> Through passion, I gain strength.
> Through strength, I gain power.
> Through power, I gain victory.
> Through victory, my chains are broken.
> The Force shall free me.

To illustrate my point, after Palpatine's death, the order lives on in 3 different cults, all of which were Sith more by self-proclamation than by classification:

*(Excerpts taken from [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Order_of_the_Sith_Lords))*

### Lumiya's Sith

> The first to confront the new Jedi Order was Lumiya's Sith, a collection of darksiders loosely related to Darth Bane's Order. As an Emperor's Hand, Lumiya had a limited knowledge of Sith teachings and dark side techniques during her tutelage under Emperor Palpatine and Darth Vader. When both Sith Lords perished at the hands of each other at the Battle of Endor, **Lumiya proclaimed herself as their successor; a Dark Lady of the Sith.** A strict adherent to the teachings of Darth Bane, Lumiya preserved the Rule of Two in her Order, and thus she searched for only one Sith apprentice to serve at her side. After passing over two failed apprentices, Flint and Carnor Jax, the Dark Lady successfully trained Jacen Solo, a grandson of Darth Vader and a Jedi Knight of the Galactic Alliance, as her successor by 40 ABY. With Lumiya's guidance, Solo accepted the Sith mantle as Darth Caedus, the first active Dark Lord of the Sith since the time of Sidious and Vader.

### Lost Tribe of Sith

> In 43 ABY, the Jedi Order discovered the **Lost Tribe of Sith, a hidden society that traced its origin to the Sith Empire of Naga Sadow. The Lost Tribe, created long before the rise of Darth Bane and the Rule of Two, was populated by many Sith individuals, all ruled by a Grand Lord.** They formed a short-lived alliance with Luke Skywalker's Jedi Order to defeat a powerful being named Abeloth, but then betrayed the Jedi with preparations for galactic conquest.

### One Sith

> The third organization that followed in the wake of Sidious's demise was the One Sith, founded by Darth Krayt. Once a Knight of the first Jedi Order, Krayt fought for the Old Republic during the Clone Wars as A'Sharad Hett. Although Hett survived the betrayal of the clone troopers during Order 66 and the subsequent Purge, his faith in the light side of the Force was destroyed by the desire for vengeance against the Galactic Empire and the Order of the Sith Lords. Hett eventually came to believe that the only way to defeat Sidious and Vader was by embracing the power of the dark side. **Though he recreated himself as Darth Krayt, the self-proclaimed Sith Lord ignored Bane's Rule of Two. Under Krayt's Rule of One, the new Sith Order included many members in its ranks, all of whom were indoctrinated with absolute loyalty to a single Dark Lord of the Sith.** In the year 130 ABY, Darth Krayt established a new Galactic Empire after seizing the Imperial throne for himself.

*(emphasis mine)*

Comment: So what are the Sith ideals and philosophies that set the Sith identity apart and above mere Dark Jedi? Also, I found out that the spirits of the ancient Sith Lords on Korriban, such as Darth Bane etc. do not recognise Krayt's order under the Rule of One as legitimate Sith. How would these dead Sith Lords factor into the question?

Comment: I've updated my post to reflect some Sith philosophies but I didn't feel like my response to your second question was worth adding to the answer. I don't really think the dead Sith Lords factor into the equation at all. They're dead and don't leave Korriban so they have no public say on what gets considered a Sith so their opinions don't matter much. Plus, if we follow that line of thinking, the original Sith would likely want to disqualify the order under Bane which I don't think matters much either.

Comment: Besides every order of Sith will think that theirs is the "true" Sith order so any dead Sith aren't going to recognize any new Sith as a true Sith.

Answer (score 0):

Darth Krayt didn't create a new order or a new Sith philosophy. He was taught the Sith principles by XoXann, one of Ajunta's servants. If anything, Krayt would be the better and 'truer' Sith since he followed the original guidelines of the foremost Sith Lords(the Dark Jedi Exiles) ergo: Ajunta Pall.

Sith is just like an atheist religion. 
It will also have *extra* branches. And I disagree with Bane; his Rule of Two sucks and is worse than Krayt's.

Comment: Can you provide the source where you got your thoughts from?

Comment: Go and check up the Legacy comics. They are the best comics in Star Wars. Like a modern Star Wars cartoon show.

Answer (score -2):

The line can never be broken. For light to exist there must be darkness. Its a yin-Yang thing.
You will always have somebody dabble more, want power faster, be arrogant to think that he/she can do it better.
The [Sith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sith) is a label for everybody that is not following the light side of the force.
take a look at this:

> The Sith are dedicated to sith philosophy and to mastering the dark
>   side of the Force. The Sith members, known as Sith Lords or Dark
>   Lords of the Sith, traditionally use the title Darth-prefix before
>   their Sith name. The Sith are the archenemies of the quasi-religious
>   Jedi and, like them, their main weapon is the lightsaber. While Jedi
>   are subservient to the Force and aid the Galactic Republic by
>   utilizing the Force for peace, knowledge and defense, the Sith prefer
>   to exploit the Force for power, aggression or personal gain; desires
>   that inevitably led to both imperial conquest and their own
>   self-destruction

Comment: No, the Sith Order is a very specific order of dark-siders that does not categorically encompass all dark-siders. They are very exclusive because of how much power and knowledge they wield and have accumulated. Most dark siders are in fact not Sith, and are known instead as Dark Jedi. The darkness can never cease to exist forever, but the Sith need not always exist. They aren't necessarily one and the same.

Comment: Well you have Ajunta and Marka and Bane and Vitiate and Sidious and Kryat and so on and so forth. Each of these is the most badass practitioner that installs himself as the supreme ruler and accumulates vast amounts of knowledge about the dark side. They all find previous writings and holocrons in ancient tombs, steal it from others or in other ways get the knowledge and the power. The line is never the same line as most of the Sith Lords do it as they see fit. Bane is the last incarnation that made the rule of 2. but before that the order has existed in many incarnations and many masters.

Comment: "The Sith is a label for everybody that is not following the light side of the force." That is false. There are plenty of non-Sith Dark Jedi in Legends, and even in [canon](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/110924/31936) now. -1

Comment: Take the Knights Of Ren for example, they are a group of Dark Siders but they are Not Sith.