# Which predictions of The Last Jedi: Darths & Droids Bingo were correct?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

[image: Porg!!! The Last Jedi Darths & Droids bingo]

The team of the Darths & Droids screencap webcomic have produced [The Last Jedi Darths & Droids bingo](http://www.darthsanddroids.net/bingo/Episode8/), which contains predictions about *Star Wars: The Last Jedi*.

> Print out [this page](http://www.darthsanddroids.net/bingo/Episode8/) and take it to your viewing of *Star Wars: The Last Jedi!* Mark off the squares whenever the indicated event happens in the movie. If you get five in a row, you win! If a friend wants to play too, reload this page for a new card.

**Which of [the predictions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msKgJ.png) were correct for the film?**

For most of the questions, a one-line answer suffices. For events that clearly didn't appear on screen, just a “no” suffices. For events that did occur, please mention the scene where it occurs. Only a very few predictions (near misses or ambiguous occurances) merit explanations, but it may be better to link to a separate question in that case (eg. [on whether Kylo Ren is a Sith](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/110922/4918)).

1. Someone gets a hand cut off
2. Someone has a bad feeling about “this”
3. BB-8's head comes off
4. C-3PO says how many forms of communication he's fluent in
5. Wilhelm scream
6. An alien talks with subtitles
7. “May the Force be with you.”
8. Something is a trap!
9. Percussive maintenance on the Millennium Falcon
10. Chewie welds something
11. R2-D2 plugs into a computer terminal socket
12. The First Order builds another giant superweapon
13. Someone we thought was dead turns out to be alive
14. A Force ghost appears
15. Someone constructs a new lightsaber
16. Jar Jar Binks
17. A new single biome planet
18. Hyperdrive malfunction
19. A yellow lightsaber
20. An alien animal attacks!
21. An asteroid field!
22. Lightsaber wield combo more epic than ever seen before
23. New fighter named after a letter of the alphabet
24. Summon bigger fish!
25. Someone serving bizarre alien drinks
26. Alien band plays music
27. Vehicle hovers when it would work just as well or better with wheels
28. Bottomless pit without a railing
29. Transparent computer display
30. Sign or display in Aurebesh script
31. A new Force ability
32. Big “Noooooo!!”
33. Someone gets Force choked
34. Alien speaks English in an ethnic accent
35. Wedge (i.e. any character is a shapeshifter)
36. Someone mentions midi-chlorians
37. Lens flare
38. Clock wipe between scenes
39. Line that gets more amusing if you replace “Force” with “pants”
40. Lightsaber used for a non-combat purpose
41. R2-D2 falls over
42. C-3PO is damaged
43. On-screen kiss
44. Someone says “I love you.”
45. John Williams score reprises a theme from original trilogy (credits don't count)
46. R2-D2 uses a tool we've never seen before
47. Scene involving food
48. Vehicle with legs
49. Giant monster based on real world insect or other small animal
50. Creature that lives in vacuum of space
51. Jedi mind trick
52. Line repeats never before repeated line from original trilogy
53. An escape pod ejects from a ship
54. Blaster shot ricochets and kills someone
55. Bigger than life size hologram
56. Someone is immune to Jedi mind tricks
57. Real world unit of measurement (e.g. metres, parsecs)
58. Running duel moves from one location to another
59. Someone foresees the future
60. Someone swings on a rope or vine
61. Character who died in first six movies mentioned by name
62. C-3PO says something about space travel
63. Kylo Ren angsts about trying to be like Vader
64. Obvious video game level scene
65. Finn uses a lightsaber again with no training
66. Someone is identified as a clone
67. A bad guy successfully shoots someone
68. Mooks firing en masse and repeatedly missing
69. Droids walk through a crossfire without getting hit
70. Sith apprentice kills master
71. Sith master arranges death of apprentice
72. A droid fixes a spaceship
73. R2-D2 sits in an astromech port in a spaceship
74. Darth X, where X prefixed with “in” is a word
75. R2-D2 projects a hologram
76. Snoke turns out to be someone we knew
77. Snoke turns out to be someone we didn't know before
78. Scene is clear visual echo of scene in Episode V
79. Luke echoes Yoda line while talking to Rey
80. Kylo Ren does truly evil thing
81. Kylo Ren angsts and can't go through with truly evil thing
82. Multiple porgs on screen at once
83. BB-8 comes face to face with BB-9E
84. Force lightning!
85. Character or event from Rogue One referenced
86. Luke and Rey are related
87. Rey goes Dark Side
88. A non-Chewbacca Wookiee
89. Luke survives to end of film
90. Leia survives to end of film

Notes.

- This question is the next episode equivalent of [Which predictions of the Force Awakens: Darths & Droids Bingo were correct?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/112251/4918)
- I won't see the movie until some time between 2017-12-24 and 2018-01-01.  I will read the answers and possibly accept one only after I've seen the movie.
- The above is a transcript [of the cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msKgJ.png) based on [David Morgan-Mar's transcript of them in a preliminary stage of the bingo](http://www.irregularwebcomic.net/draakslair/viewtopic.php?p=167108#167108).  The question is about the original cards, so whenever my transcript is incorrect, edit the above and answer about the originals.
- The bingo cards use the spelling “lightsabre”, but this post changes that to “lightsaber”, per [our meta post on the spelling of that word](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11136/4918).
- Prediction number 22 refers to the progression of later films adding more and more complicated lightsaber fight disciplines: Darth Maul wielding a two-ended lightsaber in Episode 1, General Grievous using four lightsabers at the same time in Episode 3, then Kylo Ren using a cross-shaped lightsaber in Episode 7.
- Some of the predictions may be funnier if you are familiar with the webcomic, but it should be possible to understand every prediction without that.  In particular, prediction number 35 refers to the Darths & Droids running gag that Wedge is a shapeshifter, but in this bingo Wedge is irrelevant for the prediction, the prediction is true if anyone turns out to be a shapeshifter in the film.
- [The Darths & Droids forum thread “The Last Jedi bingo (contains The Force Awakens spoilers)”](http://www.irregularwebcomic.net/draakslair/viewtopic.php?p=167108#167108) might contain some relevant discussion in the future.

Comment: 22, 35, 39 are 3 that stood out as not making any sense to me. Also do we close this as FWP until the film comes out? 52 seems difficult to tell, unless you cross-referenced all lines from all films. 48 and 78 can already be answered.

Comment: Is this an advertisement?

Comment: @Raditz_35 Not really. Even if it was, this happened for TFA as well, if I remember correctly and it wasn't closed.

Comment: Re: #22 (and the bullet explaining it): [Obligatorily awesome Russian youtube video on the topic](https://youtu.be/kgSylgBFi-I).

Comment: How does this question NOT have any VTCs? It's clearly a list question that would require an absurdly long list answer...

Comment: @Omegacron: The list is still clearly finite (like many other long lists on this site).

Comment: Really? No "C-3P0 states massively impossible odds"?

Comment: @caird coinheringaahing: DMM specifically asked for ideas on the forum before he did the bingo for The Last Jedi: http://www.irregularwebcomic.net/draakslair/viewtopic.php?p=167093 . Give such ideas *before* the next film.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Because I love teamwork, I’m making this a community wiki

*If something is up to interpretation, try to state the facts and leave the interpretation to the reader.*

1. > Someone gets a hand cut off.

   Snoke’s severed hand can be seen lying on his throne.
2. > Someone has a bad feeling about “this”.

   [According to Rian Johnson](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/83802/9391), BB-8 says it during the beginning battle against the First Order fleet, resulting in Poe saying: “Only good beeps!”
3. > BB-8’s head comes off.

   Funnily enough, yes.
4. > C-3PO says how many forms of communication he's fluent in.

   Nope
5. > Wilhelm scream.

   We have [a separate question for this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/177258/20840).
6. > An alien talks with subtitles.

   Jeremy French says *yes*, but Edlothiad doesn’t remember any.
7. > “May the Force be with you”.

   A-plenty
8. > Something is a trap!

   - Snoke manipulates Rey into thinking she can help Kylo, which leads to her capture.
   - DJ (the code breaker) leads Finn and Rose into the trap of the First Order.
9. > Percussive maintenance on the Millennium Falcon.

   Not on the Millennium Falcon, but on Snoke’s ship.  When Finn's party disables a section of the shield of Snoke's ship for just a moment to get in, we see a display show the corresponding mark in a display blink.  A technician seeing that hits the console to fix the error, and is satisfied when the mark turns on, not realizing that the display wasn't in error.
10. > Chewie welds something.

    Nope.
11. > R2-D2 plugs into a computer terminal socket.

    Yes, [near the end of the film](http://www.irregularwebcomic.net/draakslair/viewtopic.php?p=167306#167306).
12. > The First Order builds another giant superweapon.

    The closest we get are:

    - a cannon designed to destroy gates,
    - base-destroying dreadnoughts,
    - a hyperspace tracking device.
13. > Someone we thought was dead turns out to be alive.

    - Leia comes back to life.
    - Captain Phasma escaped the destruction of Starkiller Base.
    - Luke gets blown up by a bunch of new AT-ATs (but not really).
14. > A Force ghost appears.

    Yoda.
15. > Someone constructs a new lightsaber.

    Nope.
16. > Jar Jar Binks.

    Nope.
17. > A new single biome planet.

    - Crait is an entirely mineral planet.
    - Cantonica is a desert planet with a casino city (so it’s space Las Vegas).
18. > Hyperdrive malfunction.

    Nope
19. > A yellow lightsaber.

    Nope
20. > An alien animal attacks!

    There is a stampede through a city.
21. > An asteroid field!

    D’Qar is surrounded by an asteroid field.
22. > Lightsaber wield combo more epic than ever seen before.

    Possibly.  A lightsaber gets ripped in two when Kylo Ren and Rey both try to pull it with the Force.
    Snoke’s guards have some pretty cool weapon combos, but they’re not lightsabers.
23. > New fighter named after a letter of the alphabet.

    Not named at least.
24. > Summon bigger fish!

    Luke *does* kill that huge fish.
    But also on Ahch-To, there’s a big sea animal in the water with a visible spine, à la the dragonsnake in *The Empire Strikes Back*.
25. > Someone serving bizarre alien drinks.

    - Probably in the casino, though we do not get to appreciate its weirdness.
    - Luke also drinks some weird milk.
26. > Alien band plays music.

    Probably in the casino.
27. > Vehicle hovers when it would work just as well or better with wheels.

    On Cantonica, there are those common hovering cars, floating above the perfectly paved streets.
    And  Kylo’s ship flying above Gorilla AT-ATs; those skiffs chucking up salt on the red waste.
28. > Bottomless pit without a railing.

    Yes. The catwalk to the tracking device has no railing.
    A Praetorian Guard falls into a pit without railing in the Supreme Leader's throne room.  We don't see how deep the pit is, but he immediately gets shocked by a big blue lightning arc from some impressive looking machine.
29. > Transparent computer display

    Obviously...
30. > Sign or display in Aurebesh script.

    On Leia’s medbay pod.
    Also on the Canto Bight police uniforms and vehicles.
31. > A new Force ability.

    - Snoke claims he was able to link Rey and Kylo’s minds and allow them to come in contact with each other while being across the galaxy from each other.
    - Luke’s long-distance illusion at the end.
    - Leia survives outer space long enough to get pulled to an airlock, and later Luke wakes her up from her unconscious state from long distance.
32. > Big “Noooooo!!”

    Kylo shouts this after it’s revealed that Luke tricked him at the end and that the Resistance has escaped.
33. > Someone gets Force choked.

    Yes, Kylo force-chokes Hux to make sure he knows he’s the new supreme leader.
34. > Alien speaks English in an ethnic accent.

    Maz Katana makes an appearace; does that count?
35. > Wedge (i.e. any character is a shapeshifter).

    The crystal critters become really small and slip through a tiny gap.

    Note that, given their size and physical configuration (canine quadrupeds about the size of a small coyote), wriggling through this gap is well within the expected capabilities of such an animal, and doesn't require shapeshifting to explain.
36. > Someone mentions midi-chlorians.

    No, Jedi is back to being a religion.
37. > Lens flare

    - The first one is right after the opening scroll.
    - During Luke and Leia's reunion.
38. > Clock wipe between scenes

    Yes.
39. > Line that gets more amusing if you replace “Force” with “pants”.

    Luke says that the Force doesn’t belong to Jedi.
40. > Lightsaber used for non-combat purpose.

    If you count tug-of-war.
41. > R2-D2 falls over.

    Nope
42. > C-3PO is damaged.

    Nope
43. > On-screen kiss.

    - Rose and Finn.
    - Luke kisses Leia’s head.
44. > Someone says “I love you”.

    Nope, although Rose comes close.
45. > John Williams score reprises a theme from original trilogy (credits don't count)

    - Main theme (obvs),
    - opening flute cue from *A New Hope* post-crawl,
    - Princess Leia theme (EpIV),
    - Luke and Leia theme (EpVI),
    - Tie Fighter / Death Star Trench Run (EpIV),
    - Yoda’s theme (EpVI)
46. > R2-D2 uses a tool we’ve never seen before.

    Nope, but BB-8 has several.
47. > Scene involving food.

    - Luke hunts a Giant fish.
    - Chewie roasts some sort of bird (possibly a porg), upsetting the porgs.
48. > Vehicle with legs

    - BB-8 takes over a walker on Snoke’s ship.
    - AT-ATs at the end.
49. > Giant monster based on real world insect or other small animal.

    Nope.
50. > Creature that lives in vacuum of space.

    Leia survives the vacuum of space for some time but it’s not her natural habitat.
51. > Jedi mind trick.

    - Kylo attempts to force Rey to bring Skywalker to him.
    - Snoke attempts to turn Rey.
52. > Line repeats never before repeated line from original trilogy.

    Yoda repeats himself: “Pass on what you have learned.”
53. > As escape pod ejects from a ship.

    - Rey uses the Millennium Falcon’s escape pod.
54. > Blaster shot ricochets and kills someone.

    There was a ricochet off Phasma’s armor but it didn’t kill anyone.
55. > Bigger than life size hologram

    Snoke’s head shows up in big at the start.
56. > Someone is immune to Jedi mind tricks

    Not explicitly.
57. > Real world unit of measurement (e.g. metres, parsecs)

    Parsecs are used, but this time they’re used *as* a unit of length.
58. > Running duel moves from one location to another

    Nope.
59. > Someone foresees the future.

    Rey claims to have seen Kylo Ren’s future when they touched hands, and Kylo claims to have seen Rey’s.
60. > Someone swings on a rope or vine.

    No ropes or vines, but Luke jumps across on a giant pole
61. > Character who died in first six movies mentioned by name.

    - Yoda is mentioned by Luke when his force ghost appears.
    - Darth Vader is mentioned by name several times: Snoke says he intends for Kylo to become a new Vader.
    - Leia’s hologram asking Obi-Wan for help appears.
    - Luke mentions Sidious when lamenting the failure of the Jedi.
62. > C-3PO says something about space travel.

    Nope.
63. > Kylo Ren angsts about trying to be like Vader.

    Yep; he rages out and destroys his helmet.
64. > Obvious video game level scene.

    Poe destroying the turrets on the Dreadnaught. Definitely a *Lego: The Last Jedi* game scene.
65. > Finn uses a lightsaber again with no training.

    No; he isn’t anywhere near any lightsabers this time.
66. > Someone is identified as a clone.

    Nope.
67. > A bad guy successfully shoots someone.

    - Kylo successfully destroys the hangar on the Resistance cruiser and his escorts blow up the bridge.
    - A Tie fighter manages to hit Poe Dameron’s X-Wing (it’s only damaged, though).
68. > Mooks firing en masse and repeatedly missing.

    - Most of the fighting is ship-to-ship, so not really.
    - The First Order pilots and gunners actually seem pretty effective.
    - The Canto Bight police miss Finn and Rose, but they manage to destroy their ship.
69. > Droids walk through a crossfire without getting hit.

    Nope.
70. > Sith apprentice kills master.

    Kylo kills Snoke, but neither are officialy Sith.
71. > Sith master arranges death of apprentice.

    Nope, Snoke only wants Kylo to kill Rey.
72. > A droid fixes a spaceship.

    BB-8 fixes the guns on Poe starship.
73. > R2-D2 sits in an astromech port in a spaceship

    Nope, he has a quick feature; the only astromech in an astromech port we see is BB-8.
74. > Darth X, where X prefixed with “in” is a word

    Darth Vader and Darth Sidious. No *new* Darths, though.
75. > R2-D2 projects a hologram

    He cheekily projects Luke to remind him of the message that Leia sent him long ago. He is now their *only hope*.
76. > Snoke turns out to be someone we knew

    We don’t find out who Snoke is.
77. > Snoke turns out to be someone we didn't know before

    We don’t find out who Snoke is.
78. > Scene is clear visual echo of scene in Episode V.

    The Gorilla AT-ATs attack on Crait is a direct mirror of the attack on Hoth.
79. > Luke echoes Yoda line while talking to Rey.

    Nope.
80. > Kylo Ren does truly evil thing.

    He chooses to become Supreme Leader of the First Order.
81. > Kylo Ren angsts and can’t go through with truly evil thing.

    Yep, couldn’t kill Leia or Rey.
82. > Multiple porgs on screen at once.

    Loads of times all over Ahch-To.
83. > BB-8 comes face to face with BB-9E

    After BB-9E reveals that BB-8, Finn and Rose break into Snoke’s ship with the codebreaker.
84. > Force lightning!

    - Snoke uses it on Kylo.
    - Yoda summons lightning through the Force.
85. > Character or event from Rogue One referenced.

    - The Resistance cruiser is named the *[Raddus](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Raddus_(MC85_Star_Cruiser))*, after the *Rogue One* admiral. (This is only named in promotional and tie-in materials, and not the movie itself.)
    - The First Order has developed Hyperspace tracking, which Jyn sees a file for while looking through the Imperial archives.
86. > Luke and Rey are related.

    There is no indication in that direction. In fact, [if Kylo Ren is to be trusted on this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/176362/20840), Rey’s parents were junk traders.
87. > Rey goes Dark Side.

    Almost, but not quite, she ends up saving the resistance from Kylo.
88. > A non-Chewbacca Wookiee

    Nope.
89. > Luke survives to end of film.

    Nope; he pulls an Obi-wan after teasing Kylo and Force Ghosts away while meditating on a rock on Ach-To.
90. > Leia survives to end of film.

    Looks like it; she gets on the Falcon at the end.

Comment: Re recycled dialog, I remember three it four times clocking it while watching but can't think which lines now.

Comment: I believe that they mean what is essentially a stormtrooper by "mook".  I guess the best definition would be "random henchman".

Comment: 27.: How was that casino word called? They had those common hovering cars on their paved Mediterranian streets... (may be a better one, I believe Kylo was actually sitting in a ship)

Comment: Canto Bight was the casino. Cantonica was the planet

Comment: 39. It's time for the pants to end.

Comment: I believe at some point in TLJ Poe gives a big dramatic Noooooo! (point 32) Though I may be getting confused because I saw it in a double bill with TFA.

Comment: The plans for hyperspace tracking are first talked about in Rogue One so I'd say that's a reference for 86.

Comment: Wilhelm scream occurs when Luke is performing a sick dodge under Kylo Ren's lightsaber--it's masked as the sound of the lightsaber. :\ Epic moment ruined by goofy sound.

Comment: @gntskn, can you explain *when* those things you added occur? (Actually, looks like someone already explained the lens flare, but where/when did you see a clock wipe between scenes?)

Comment: @Marisa do you have a source for that?

Comment: @Edlothiad Until someone uploads the clip, no. But I am 100% certain I heard it.

Comment: @Marisa guess it's another rewatch for me :)

Comment: For 69, does shooting at a force projection count as missing?

Comment: @Ethan Well they're not really _hitting_ anything, but theoretically he should've turned to dust.

Comment: Parsecs might be used as length or not. He says just a few parsecs. This would work with just a few minutes as well as just a few miles. They played it safe.

Comment: @DavidStarkey: I am pretty sure that it was “It’s time for the Jedi too end”.

Comment: 78. Scene is clear visual echo of scene in Episode V.  Too many to count.

Comment: Perhaps this answer would be more useful (or at least user-friendly) if it was sorted into "Yes," "No," and "Ambiguous" headings.

Comment: @EmoryBell it’s sorted as such because the original predictions are sorted as such. Have a list of No’s with random numbers would look a bit off to me, and users would have to search around for the answer they may want to find.

Comment: "17 Cantonica is a desert planet with a casino city (so it’s space Las Vegas)" - clearly, we need an Elvis impersonator singing "Viva Spahs Vegas"!

Answer (score -1):

A few corrections regarding things I noticed during watching the movie:

17. A new single biome planet.

Possibly, we don't see much of Crait or Cantonica.

-> I would exchange "possibly" with "maybe". There's no way to tell either way.

27. Vehicle hovers when it would work just as well or better with wheels.

Kylo's ship flying above Gorilla AT-ATs, those skiffs chucking up salt on the red waste.

-> How would Kylos ship work as well or even better with wheels? It flies to have a better overview, that would not be possible on wheels. And with the skiffs, as they start flying in higher altitude when they leave the base, without repulsors that could get nasty when they land...

28. Bottomless pit without a railing.

Nope.

-> Not sure, there's one scene inside Snokes big ship where they show the enormous size inside viewing upways. I wouldn't rule out that there were pits as well. Though "bottomless" would of course be technically wrong, but that's the case with any occurence so far ;)

30. Sign or display in Aurebesh script.

Yes? Maybe. Real answer: ¯_(?)_/¯

-> definitely on Canto Bight, several times. For example, the law enforcement people had "CBPD" in Aurebesh on their helmets.

35. Wedge (i.e. any character is a shapeshifter).

The "crystal critters" become really small and slip through a tiny gap.

-> really, they shapeshifted? Don't forget, animals might be able to pull that of even without that ability, cats for example are able to squeeze through very small places where you wouldn't think that possible as well.

37. Lens flare

¯_(?)_/¯

-> definitly, though only in small amounts, for example when Luke talks to Leia.

39. Line that gets more amusing if you replace “Force” with “pants”.

God knows, "May the pants be with you"?

-> doesn't every line using the word "Force" count? ;)

45. John Williams score reprises a theme from original trilogy (credits don't count)

Yes, the original theme features at some point in the film.

-> the combat theme gets a heavy reprise as well

47. Scene involving food.

Luke hunts a Giant fish.

-> Not to forget Chewie trying to eat a Porg...

53. As escape pod ejects from a ship.

Yep, the resistance fleeing from their minor ships to the cruisers as they run out of fuel.

-> Rey leaves the Falcon in an escape pod, I think

61. Character who died in first six movies mentioned by name.

Yoda's ghost appears? Darth Vader is mentioned by name, Leia's hologram asking Obi-Wan for help appears. That's about it.

-> Luke mentions Palpatine, when talking about the downfall of the Jedi.

68. A bad guy successfully shoots someone.

Kylo successfully destroys the Hanger on the Resistance cruiser and blows up the bridge

-> Actually, it wasn't Kylo blowing up the bridge but his accompanying minions.

71. Sith apprentice kills master.

Yep! Kylo kills Snoke!

-> But Kylo or Snoke are never referenced as being Sith

Hope that helps!

Comment: A community wiki answer was created to be edited into. You can leave your answer here but it's normally good practice to add it to the Community answer.