# Which predictions of The Rise of Skywalker: Darths & Droids Bingo were correct?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

The team of the Darths & Droids screencap webcomic have produced [The Rise of Skywalker Bingo](https://www.darthsanddroids.net/bingo/Episode9/), which contains predictions about *Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker*.

> Print out this page and take it to your viewing of *Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker*! Mark off the squares whenever the indicated event happens in the movie. If you get five in a row, you win! If a friend wants to play too, reload this page for a new card.

**Which of the predictions were correct for the film?**

For most of the questions, a one-line answer suffices. For events that clearly didn't appear on screen, just a “no” suffices. For events that did occur, please mention the scene where it occurs. Only a very few predictions (near misses or ambiguous occurences) merit explanations, but it may be better to link to a separate question in that case.

1. Someone gets a hand cut off
2. Someone has a bad feeling about “this”
3. BB-8 has a new attachment/tool/appendage
4. C-3PO says how many forms of communication he's fluent in
5. Wilhelm scream
6. An alien talks with subtitles
7. “May the Force be with you.”
8. Something is a trap!
9. Percussive maintenance on the Millennium Falcon
10. Chewie welds something
11. R2-D2 plugs into a computer terminal socket
12. The First Order builds another giant superweapon
13. Someone we thought was dead turns out to be alive
14. A Force ghost appears
15. Someone constructs a new lightsaber
16. Character we haven't seen since the prequel trilogy
17. A new single biome planet
18. Hyperdrive malfunction
19. A yellow lightsaber
20. An alien animal attacks!
21. An asteroid field!
22. Lightsaber wield combo more epic than ever seen before
23. New fighter named after a letter of the alphabet
24. Summon bigger fish!
25. Someone serving bizarre alien drinks
26. Alien band plays music
27. Vehicle hovers when it would work just as well or better with wheels
28. Bottomless pit without a railing
29. Transparent computer display
30. Sign or display in Aurebesh script
31. A new Force ability
32. Big “Noooooo!!”
33. Someone gets Force choked
34. New cute animal designed to sell merchandise
35. Wedge (i.e. any character is a shapeshifter)
36. Character rides some sort of alien animal
37. Lens flare
38. Clock wipe between scenes
39. Line that gets more amusing if you replace “Force” with “pants”
40. Lightsaber used for a non-combat purpose
41. R2-D2 falls over
42. C-3PO is damaged
43. On-screen kiss
44. Someone says “I love you.”
45. John Williams score reprises a theme from original trilogy (credits don't count)
46. Somebody seems to fall off a precipice (but climbs up)
47. Scene involving food
48. Vehicle with legs
49. Giant monster based on real world insect or other small animal
50. Creature that lives in vacuum of space
51. Jedi mind trick
52. Spaceship does a manoeuvre just to look cool in 3D
53. An escape pod ejects from a ship
54. Blaster shot ricochets and kills someone
55. Bigger than life size hologram
56. Someone is immune to Jedi mind tricks
57. Kylo Ren goes Light Side
58. Running duel moves from one location to another
59. Someone foresees the future
60. Someone swings on a rope or vine
61. Character who died in first six movies mentioned by name
62. C-3PO says something about space travel
63. Kylo Ren angsts about trying to be like Vader
64. Obvious video game level scene
65. Finn uses a lightsaber again with no training
66. Someone is identified as a clone
67. A bad guy successfully shoots someone
68. Mooks firing en masse and repeatedly missing
69. Droids walk through a crossfire without getting hit
70. Events in space as seen from a planet's surface
71. Somebody disguises themself to infiltrate somewhere
72. A droid fixes a spaceship
73. Gratuitous topless Kylo Ren
74. Cyborg animal
75. R2-D2/BB-8 projects a hologram
76. Snoke turns out to be someone we knew
77. Character seen in a previous film uses the Force for the first time
78. Scene is clear visual echo of scene in Episode VI
79. Kylo Ren reclaims Ben Solo name
80. Kylo Ren does truly evil thing
81. Kylo Ren angsts and can't go through with truly evil thing
82. Cyborg character
83. BB-8 comes face to face with BB-9E
84. Force lightning!
85. Character or event from Rogue One referenced
86. Luke and Rey are related
87. Rey goes Dark Side
88. A non-Chewbacca Wookiee
89. “I have spoken” OR “This is the way”
90. Leia survives to end of film
91. Something begins a self-destruct sequence
92. Something IN CAPITAL LETTERS in the opening crawl
93. A hive of scum and villainy
94. A character sacrifices themself
95. C-3PO states massively impossible odds
96. A character realises that they are now a Sith
97. A force ghost haunts a character
98. Snoke returns
99. Anakin returns
100. Palpatine/Darth Sidious returns
101. Past Sith other than Sidious or Vader

Notes.

- The analogous question about the previous two big films were [Which predictions of the Force Awakens: Darths & Droids Bingo were correct?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/112251/4918) and [Which predictions of The Last Jedi: Darths & Droids Bingo were correct?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/176043/4918)
- I haven't seen the movie yet, so I won't read the answers until that.
- The question is about [the original bingo cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/264cJ.png), so whenever my transcript is incorrect, edit the question and answer about the actual cards.
- The bingo cards use the spelling “lightsabre”, but this post changes that to “lightsaber”.
- Some of the predictions may be funnier if you are familiar with the webcomic, but it should be possible to understand every prediction without that.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot it's still *too broad* imho.

Comment: @ColumbiasaysReinstateMonica It's a finite list and the previous two for the other two films are still open and were well received. It's also a lot less broad than some mass character ID questions that have been ruled on topic.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

*Long have I waited to answer this question.*

*I will try to answer this as best I can from memory. If anyone has additional information, feel free to add it.*

1. **Someone gets a hand cut off.** – No.
2. **Someone has a bad feeling about “this”.** – Of course, Lando Calrissian.
3. **BB-8 has a new attachment/tool/appendage.** – Maybe, we see him tinkering around with things.
4. **C-3PO says how many forms of communication he’s fluent in.** – May happen when he refuses to translate Sith (Poe mentions it) and after he got rebooted.
5. **Wilhelm scream.** – ?
6. **An alien talks with subtitles.** – Yes, Nien Nunb at the Resistance base.
7. **“May the Force be with you.”** – Yes.
8. **Something is a trap!** – No.
9. **Percussive maintenance on the Millennium Falcon.** – I don't recall.
10. **Chewie welds something.** – No.
11. **R2-D2 plugs into a computer terminal socket.** – Yes, but with a large data cable.
12. **The First Order builds another giant superweapon.** – Kind of; now they come standard on all their ships.
13. **Someone we thought was dead turns out to be alive.** – Chewbacca and Palpatine and Kylo Ren and Rey and...actually, maybe it is better to just list the people who don't fit.
14. **A Force ghost appears.** – Yes.
15. **Someone constructs a new lightsaber.** – Yes, at the very end.
16. **Character we haven’t seen since the prequel trilogy.** – Palpatine, if you consider the production timeline and not the in-universe timeline. Also, the Jedi voices Rey hears at the end feature several matches, most noticeably Mace Windu.
17. **A new single biome planet.** – But of course: Ajan Kloss (the Resistance base), Pasaana, Kijimi, Exegol (for a liberal definition of *biome*).
18. **Hyperdrive malfunction.** – Yes.
19. **A yellow lightsaber.** – Yes.
20. **An alien animal attacks!** – Several.
21. **An asteroid field!** – Yes, the heroes wait in one after Pasaana while they are figuring out what to do about C-3PO’s inability to reveal to them the Wayfinder’s coordinates.
22. **Lightsaber wield combo more epic than ever seen before.** – Two lightsabers in the shape of an X; swapping lightsabers via Force teleportation.
23. **New fighter named after a letter of the alphabet.** – At least not named on screen.
24. **Summon bigger fish!** – No.
25. **Someone serving bizarre alien drinks.** – In the bar on Kijimi.
26. **Alien band plays music.** – Yes.
27. **Vehicle hovers when it would work just as well or better with wheels.** – Yes.
28. **Bottomless pit without a railing.** – On Exegol.
29. **Transparent computer display.** – Yes.
30. **Sign or display in Aurebesh script.** – Yes.
31. **A new Force ability.** – Teleportation, healing, mind transfer.
32. **Big “Noooooo!!”** – Probably.
33. **Someone gets Force choked.** – Some First Order big wig who did not fully like Kylo Ren’s changes to his mask.
34. **New cute animal designed to sell merchandise.** – Matter of opinion. Return of the porgs as well.
35. **Wedge (i.e. any character is a shapeshifter).** – No. Also, Wedge is a shapeshifter?
36. **Character rides some sort of alien animal.** – Yes.
37. **Lens flare.** – Yes.
38. **Clock wipe between scenes.** – I can’t recall any.
39. **Line that gets more amusing if you replace “Force” with “pants”.** – Not in my opinion.
40. **Lightsaber used for a non-combat purpose.** – Yes, as a light source.
41. **R2-D2 falls over.** – No.
42. **C-3PO is damaged.** – Yes.
43. **On-screen kiss.** – Yes.
44. **Someone says “I love you.”** – No.
45. **John Williams score reprises a theme from original trilogy (credits don't count).** – But of course.
46. **Somebody seems to fall off a precipice (but climbs up).** – At least twice.
47. **Scene involving food.** – Yes.
48. **Vehicle with legs.** – Some runners on Kajimi.
49. **Giant monster based on real world insect or other small animal.** – That worm on Pasaana.
50. **Creature that lives in vacuum of space.** – One is spotted in the first act when Poe is escaping from some Tie Fighters.
51. **Jedi mind trick.** – Rey on stormtroopers when trying to free Chewbacca.
52. **Spaceship does a manoeuvre just to look cool in 3D.** – Yes.
53. **An escape pod ejects from a ship.** – No.
54. **Blaster shot ricochets and kills someone.** – No, unless you count ricochetting off a light sabre.
55. **Bigger than life size hologram.** – Yes, Palpatine.
56. **Someone is immune to Jedi mind tricks.** – No.
57. **Kylo Ren goes Light Side.** – He renounces the First Order, uses a blue lightsaber, and fights against the Knights of Ren and Palpatine, and his body disappears after his death.
58. **Running duel moves from one location to another.** – Kylo Ren vs. Rey on the Death Star wreck.
59. **Someone foresees the future.** – Yes.
60. **Someone swings on a rope or vine.** – Averted. Rey’s obstacle course features a vine to get over a chasm, but she just force-jumps.
61. **Character who died in first six movies mentioned by name.** – Palpatine (if you count him).
62. **C-3PO says something about space travel.** – ?
63. **Kylo Ren angsts about trying to be like Vader.** – ?
64. **Obvious video game level scene.** – Opinion.
65. **Finn uses a lightsaber again with no training.** – Finn was extensively trained in hand-to-hand combat, and it’s hinted that he might be Force-sensitive. That said, he does not use a lightsaber in this film.
66. **Someone is identified as a clone.** – Yes: “I made Snoke.”
67. **A bad guy successfully shoots someone.** – Poe gets shot on the star destroyer; Hux shoots some goons (albeit while helping the Resistance); Pryde shoots Hux.
68. **Mooks firing en masse and repeatedly missing.** – For example on the star destroyer.
69. **Droids walk through a crossfire without getting hit.** – Maybe.
70. **Events in space as seen from a planet's surface.** – The Battle of Exegol, which happened half in space.
71. **Somebody disguises themself to infiltrate somewhere.** – Kind of. If you count large hoodies as disguises, then the crew led by Poe try to get C3PO to a droid technician on Kajimi.
72. **A droid fixes a spaceship.** – Maybe.
73. **Gratuitous topless Kylo Ren.** – No.
74. **Cyborg animal.** – No.
75. **R2-D2/BB-8 projects a hologram.** – No.
76. **Snoke turns out to be someone we knew.** – No.
77. **Character seen in a previous film uses the Force for the first time.** – Finn has a Force hunch on which star destroyer is the one sending the steering signal.
78. **Scene is clear visual echo of scene in Episode VI.** – Yes, yes, of course.
79. **Kylo Ren reclaims Ben Solo name.** – Obviously yes.
80. **Kylo Ren does truly evil thing.** – Several.
81. **Kylo Ren angsts and can't go through with truly evil thing.** – He seems to be having some reluctance about killing Rey even before Leia distracts him. Besides which, he angsts about the evil action of serving Palpatine afterward, and ultimately decides he can't do it.
82. **Cyborg character.** – Yes.  The repairmen who welds Kylo Ren's mask has a robotic visor.
83. **BB-8 comes face to face with BB-9E.** – No.
84. **Force lightning!** – On Pasaana, Rey accidentally fries the ship on which she presumes Chewbacca. Used by Palpatine on Rey, Kylo Ren, and the entire enemy fleet!
85. **Character or event from Rogue One referenced.** – No.
86. **Luke and Rey are related.** – If Palpatine is actually behind Anakin's birth as the comics suggest; so from a certain point of view …
87. **Rey goes Dark Side.** – Very briefly, but yes.
88. **A non-Chewbacca Wookiee.** – No.
89. **“I have spoken” OR “This is the way”.** – ?
90. **Leia survives to end of film.** – No.
91. **Something begins a self-destruct sequence.** – No.
92. **Something IN CAPITAL LETTERS in the opening crawl.** – Yes: *Revenge, Emperor Palpatine, General Leia Organa, Rey, First Order, Kylo Ren.*
93. **A hive of scum and villainy.** – Possibly Kajimi.
94. **A character sacrifices themself.** – Yes, and how: C3PO, Leia, Rey, Kylo, Hux after a fashion.
95. **C-3PO states massively impossible odds.** – Nope.
96. **A character realises that they are now a Sith.** – Not really. Palpatine insists that Rey is a Sith but I don't think she agrees.
97. **A force ghost haunts a character.** – Kind of: Leia spooks Kylo Ren during his battle with Rey on the Death Star wreck.
98. **Snoke returns.** – No, but both his voice and his clones make brief appearances.
99. **Anakin returns.** – Only his spirit.
100. **Palpatine/Darth Sidious returns.** – At last, my boy. Long have I waited. I have been every voice you have ever heard inside your head.
101. **Past Sith other than Sidious or Vader.** – Palpatine claims to be “all Sith”. Also, their spirits seem to be in the stands watching Palpatine.

Comment: 94. C-3PO (allows his memory to probably be wiped)

Comment: I think C3-P0 gives his "I am fluent in over..." speech after he gets rebooted. Also, Pryde successfully shot Hux. Lastly, the hooded guys might just be cultists??

Comment: 44. Finn tells Rey there's something he never told her, before getting sucked into the quicksand.

Comment: @MrLister - Doesn't count. He didn't say the words, and it is even possible he meant something else (like that he is Force-sensitive).

Comment: 1. The last extra Kylo was fighting against to get the first Wayfinder at the start of the movie.

Comment: 82. (Maybe) the person who welded Kylo’s old helmet back together.

Comment: 35. Wedge (not a shapeshifter?) was on the Falcon as a gunner at the end battle with Chewie and Lando.

Comment: @CTMacUser - That one confused me.

Comment: @Adamant I think that they were saying "Some minor character from the OT returns (Wedge is an example, but it could be anyone." Thus, Nien Num could have counted for it, or if we found out that Dac had somehow survived, he would have counted.

Comment: Also, 65: Finn holds onto Rey's lightsaber in the worm den. He never uses it for combat, he just holds it.

Comment: 97: Han's "memory" is basically a Force Ghost returning to haunt Kylo Ren.

Comment: @NegativeFriction - Then what is all that about shapeshifting?

Comment: counting all the "maybe" as 0.5, it makes a total of around 62/100.

Comment: @Quasi_Stomach  - That "rant" is necessary to note that the question as formulated contains an explicit error (Finn has no training) and an implicit one (he shouldn't be as good as he is).

Comment: 44. I know it doesn't count, but I'd like to make an honerable mention of the Han and Kylo scene.

Comment: I believe Wedge is there near the end.

Comment: @Michael - As I understand it, they are looking for shapeshifters, which Wedge is not canonically. I assume this is a joke about the comic.

Comment: @Adamant "Wedge (i.e. any character is a shapeshifter)" is just a reference to Wedge in the Darths and Droids comic, where he *is* a shapeshifter.

Comment: Exactly. I interpret it as asking about shapeshifter, which Wedge isn't in the film.

Comment: There is a long running complaint in Darths and Droids about how there are canonically shapeshifters in the SW universe (the assassin in II was one), and absolutely nothing is done with this piece of worldbuilding. So in the comic, Wedge (and Greedo, sort of) were made into shapeshifters.

Comment: @ArcanistLupus I also believe there was a case in some media of the wrong pilot being identified as Wedge on Yavin IV, or something to that effect (effectively leading to 2 different faces/people both identified as Wedge). Maybe it's a reference to this as well? (My memory is unfortunately very rusty on the details of this confusion, though).

Comment: I can show you what the Wilhelm scream is but it will change your cinematic experience forever. If you are brave enough: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HNvZYzg7o68

Comment: The Wilhelm Scream hasn't been used in any Star Wars movie since The Force Awakens in 2015, and according to sound editor Matthew Wood in 2018, Lucasfilm has decided to abandon use of the scream in favor of a new stock sound effect from Lucas' film "American Graffiti" dubbed The George. It has, however, appeared in episodes of The Clone Wars, Rebels, and The Bad Batch released after 2015. https://www.radiotimes.com/movies/a-long-running-star-wars-tradition-has-been-put-to-rest/